# ActionBar customization with Theme.Compat error

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-styles

I am trying to use the support library to give a style to the ActionBar, but I am getting the same error and I cant make it work

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

It was working good when I didnt use the AppCompat library but when I implement with the support library it stop working
There is my code

Manifest: `android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"`

values style:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/fondoNavigation</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/letraNavigation</item>
</style>

<style name="BotonMenu">
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">210dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Toggle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toggle_button_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textOn"></item>
    <item name="android:textOff"></item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">75px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">34px</item>
</style>
```

values-v11

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>



<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/fondoNavigation</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/letraNavigation</item>
</style>

<style name="BotonMenu">
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">210dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Toggle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toggle_button_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textOn"></item>
    <item name="android:textOff"></item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">75px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">34px</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

Comment: @D4rWiNS, do you use toolbar in this activity?